# Logical error in c ,program with Irrational answer

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#define false 0
#define true 1

int isprime(int a) {
    for (i=1; i<=a; i++) {
        if (a%i==0) {
            sum=sum+i;
        }
    }
    if (sum==a+1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}

int main() {
    int x,i,c,b,z=1;
    printf("please enter a number;\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    while(x<=2) {
        printf("please enter a number;\n");
        scanf("%d",&x);
    }
    for (i=3; i<=x/2; i++) {
        b=x-i;
        c=i;
        if (isprime(b) && isprime©) {
            printf("%d + %d = %d\n",b,c,x);
            z =0;
        }
    }
    if (z==1);{
        printf("impossible");
    }
}
```

A C program that is supposed to receive a number from the user and, if possible, write this number as a total of two prime numbers but  in output for prime numbers it print impossible with Add two numbers

Comment: Hint: how many times will your `for` loop runs if the user enters 3, 4, or 5?

Comment: Hint 2: Goldbach's conjecture is only for even numbers.

Comment: Hint 3: For 4, the right answer is 2 + 2.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica one time

Comment: I disagree. What do you think the value of `i` would be that one time?

Comment: Please debug your program, insert a `printf()` here and there at least.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica i think your execute have a problem i dont have this results in may PC

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica  thank you so much for your spending time guys i give my answer

Comment: Consider `#include <stdbool.h>` instead of defining true and false.

Answer (score 0):

Error is here

```
if (z==1);{printf("impossible");}
```

It should be

```
if (z==1){printf("impossible");}
```

You cannot ; after your if

After removing:

[image: output]

Prior to removing:

[image: prior output]

As per @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica recommendation. There is another logical flaw at

```
for (i=3; i<=x/2; i++)
```

which should be changed to

```
for(i=2;i<=x/2;i++)
```

The smallest prime starts at 2 not 3

Comment: While this isn't wrong, it's far from the only reason that "impossible" is printed when it shouldn't be.

Comment: It is not the only logical error but it is the error causing impossible to be printed when a number has been broken down into its prime.

Comment: My point is that sometimes the program will fail to break down a number into two primes for no reason. For example, 4 should become 2 + 2, but it doesn't because of another bug.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica understood! Thanks for informing